# Wait until async finish, then save the data in variables

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm totally newbie in JavaScript ... I have this code:

```
const MMKV = new MMKVStorage.Loader().initialize();

async function getData() {
  let role = await MMKV.getStringAsync("role");
  if (role === "distribuidor") {
    consumerKey = Constants.Keys.distributorConsumerKey;
    consumerSecret = Constants.Keys.distributorConsumerSecret;
    return [consumerKey, consumerSecret];
  }
};

let data = getData();

let consumerKey = data[0];
let consumerSecret = data[1];

export default {

  WooCommerce: {
  url: "https://xxxxx.com/",
  consumerKey,
  consumerSecret,
},
```

But consumerKey and consumerSecret are always undefined...

I know (I think) it's because the getData () function is asynchronous, and when I save the data in the variables, the function is not finished executing yet, but I don't know how to do it right. I have been quite a while, I have read about the callback functions, the promises, ... And I think the solution may go there, but I am very lost.

I would greatly appreciate a help. Thank you so much everyone.

Regards.

Comment: ```let data = await getData();``` should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have started doing something asynchronous, your code can't return results synchronously.

You have multiple options to solve this problem (neither will 'synchronize' the code):

- Use the [Top-level await proposal  (currently at Stage 3)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). That's the only way in which you can properly export things asynchronously. If this feature isn't currently  available to you, you can transpile your code with tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

  ```
    let data = await getData();

    let consumerKey = data[0];
    let consumerSecret = data[1];

    export default {

      WooCommerce: {
        url: "https://xxxxx.com/",
        consumerKey,
        consumerSecret,
      },
    }
  ```
- Use an IIAFE (Immediately Invoked Async Function Expression) wrapper:

  ```
    (async () => {
      let data = await getData();

      let consumerKey = data[0];
      let consumerSecret = data[1];

      //More code here
    )()
  ```

  You'll have to export a promise, not a value, like this:

  ```
    export default {
      WooCommerce: (async() => {
        let data = await getData();

        let consumerKey = data[0];
        let consumerSecret = data[1];

        return {
          url: "https://xxxxx.com/",
          consumerKey,
          consumerSecret,
        };
      })(),
    }
  ```
- `then` it!

  ```
    getData()
      .then(data => {

        let consumerKey = data[0];
        let consumerSecret = data[1];

        //More code here
      })
  ```

  You'll also have to export a promise, not a value, like this:

  ```
    export default {
      WooCommerce: getData()
        .then(data => {

          let consumerKey = data[0];
          let consumerSecret = data[1];

          return {
            url: "https://xxxxx.com/",
            consumerKey,
            consumerSecret,
          };
        }),
    }
  ```

Comment: Hi FZs, but "export default" is executed before function ends, how could I fix that?

Thanks to everyone, I am learning how it works.

Comment: @jaime Sorry, I haven't noticed your `export` statement. I've edited my answer now, take a look

Answer (score 1):

getDate() return a promise you have to add .then and move your code inside it

```js
getDate().then(data=>{
let consumerKey = data[0];
let consumerSecret = data[1];
})
```

Comment: you don't need `let data` any more

Comment: any thing that is using `consumerKey` or `consumerSecret` shall be written inside then

Comment: for more details about the promises and how to use it or deal with it  check this website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise